# MapView won't zoom to the annotation

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I created an annotation on my `MKMapView`, and then coded it so that it would zoom to that annotation, but it does not work.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
[mapview setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
[mapview setZoomEnabled:YES];
[mapview setScrollEnabled:YES];

CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.495554, -80.055538);
MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01f,0.01f);
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(center,span);

newClass *ann = [[newClass alloc]init];
ann.title = @"Romans Dojo";
ann.subtitle = @"Belview PA";
ann.coordinate = region.center;
[mapview addAnnotation:ann];

[mapview setRegion: region animated: YES];
region.center.latitude = 40.495554;
region.center.longitude = -80.055538;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
```

Comment: Does the annotation appear at least (zoom all the way out manually to check)?  Do you have any other setRegion calls in the app that might be changing the map region after this call?  Do you have userTrackingMode turned on to follow the user's location (which may be far from that annotation)?  Where is this code called from?

Comment: Thanks for answering! Yes the annotation does appear when i zoom out. I do not have any other setRegion or userTrackingMode turned on. The code is called in the viewDidLoad of the implementation file of the second view controller

Comment: The code looks ok.  Try setting animated to NO in the setRegion call.  Try moving the code to viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear.

Comment: Thank you so much! When I changed it to the viewDidAppear :(BOOL)animated it worked flawlessy! You saved me much frustration!

Answer (score 0):

```
mapView.map.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(center, 600, 600);
```